# Is this a good practice on Laravel?

Tags: php, html, forms, security, laravel-8

I am studying Laravel 8 and trying to make a form validation and I want to know whether my `$_POST` is right? Or is there a better way to do this or do I have problems with my code?

See my code below:

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers ;

 use illuminate\Http\Request ;
 


 class customers extends Controller {

    public function getData (Request $request){

        $name = $_POST['name']; // <--- is this right ?

    }
       
 }
```

Comment: why are u using $_POST ?

Comment: Really you validate the verb with which they send the request directly in the route `Route::get(...);` `Route::post(...);` and so on

Comment: Use `$request->name` or `$request->input('name')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has built-in functionality for working with input data.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#input

In your case, you'd want to do:

```
$name = $request->input('name');
```

Among other things, this'll protect you from the "Undefined index" errors you'd get if the `name` field is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;



class customers extends Controller {

    public function getData (Request $request){

    // $name = $_POST['name']; // <--- this is not a right method to get any value in laravel we have to using Illuminate\Http\Request; for get any post and get value

    $name = $request->name;

 }
   
}
```

here is the document link for check [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#accessing-the-request)